# Assigning Dynamic Background Images with :before

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, sass

I have a set of blog posts that is designed as such:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/x4ta8bjcua2rspz/Screenshot%202014-01-30%2020.01.20.png

The current CSS/SCSS code I'm using to make it possible is:

```
#post-group:before {
content: "";
background-image: url(@img-url);
background-size: cover;
background-position: 50% 50%;
opacity: 0.2;
top: 0;
left: 0;
bottom: 0;
right: 0;
position: absolute;
z-index: -1;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

The problem I have is that for each post, I would like to provide it a unique background image to allow the user to differentiate the posts.

Unfortunately, since I'm not using inline CSS code like this:

```
<div style="background-image:url(@img-url)"></div>
```

How can assign dynamic images to each post using :before that is in a static.css.scss file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that due to asset pre compilation you won't actually be able to dynamically change the background in the CSS. You can however, have multiple CSS styles and dynamically use them in your ERB html files by using tags within the class="" attribute of your DOM elements.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found was actually having two separate divs:

```
<div class="container">

 <!-- Place background image with the same CSS function as above, leave background-image blank -->
 <div id="post-group" style="background-image: url(@img-url);">
 </div>

 <!-- Provide Content -->
 <div class="section-post">
     <h3><%= link_to post.title, post %></h3>
     <p class="summary"><em><%= truncate(post.summary, length: 110) %></em></p>
     <p><%= link_to "read more", post, :class => "read-more" %></p>
 </div>

</div>
```

This method is actually functional since the links can be clickable, too.